# change mysql datatype column from string to json

Tags: mysql, update, json

I have an database column "image" with links to the image of the user on the server. In the next update I need to obtain multiple images, so I'm trying to change the datatype of the column to JSON.

I already put a {" before and "} after the strings. So now the values of the column looks like:

```
{"/users/57/user-11.png"}
```

When I try to update the table by:

```
ALTER TABLE ah_website_dev2.vendor_horses MODIFY COLUMN image json;
```

I get following error message:

```
Error Code: 3140. Invalid JSON text: "Missing a colon after a name of object member." at position 27 in value for column '#sql-1d30_44.image'.  0.011 sec
```

Comment: Create new field of JSON datatype. Update this field from old (image) field using proper function(s). Check the result. Drop old field, rename new.

Comment: `{"/users/57/user-11.png"}` is invalid JSON

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name missing a ";" or something?

Comment: See [The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) for correct JSON literal format.

Comment: *is this valid?* No. Read user manual please.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst a JSON field may do what you want, consider proper Data Normalisation rules first.

As soon as you want "more than one" of something, you should be thinking about a *new* table that contains those multiple instances, with a foreign key back to the table that contained "the one" thing previously.

```
select * from vendor_horses ; 

+----+---------+
| id | name    | 
+----+---------+
|  1 | Red Rum |
+----+---------+

select * from vendor_horse_images ; 

+----+-------+-----------------------+
| id | vh_id | path                  | 
+----+-------+-----------------------+
| 22 |     1 | /users/57/user-11.png |
| 33 |     1 | /users/57/user-73.png |
+----+-------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

`{"/users/57/user-11.png"}` is not valid json.

You could try something like `{"link":"/users/57/user-11.png"}`.

However, the json data type looks an odd choice for such values. A correct (and basic) way to do this would be to create a table "links" with one column ID and one string column, and then use vendor_horse_images.path as a FK referencing the path IDs in the new table